# Duplicate or same record in select query

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I tried to execute a select query which I select from the different tables but I still getting duplicate record even I use "DISTINCT". Below I attached the result from my query.

```
SELECT DISTINCT CSC.POLICYNO 
    ,PSA.WORKFLOWID 
    ,CSC.POLICYHOLDERNAME
    ,CSC.TASKTYPE 
    ,CSC.PRODUCTCODE
    ,WF.STATUS
    ,(SELECT concat(USR.SFIRSTNAME, USR.SLASTNAME) where USR.lseqid = (select psa.userid where psa.actiontype IN(602))) AS DE_Name
    ,PSA.CREATEDATE AS DE_Start_date
    ,(SELECT UPDATEDATE FROM C_WF_PS_AUDITTRAIL WHERE WORKFLOWID = PSA.WORKFLOWID AND  ACTIONTYPE IN (603) ) as DE_End_date
FROM C_WF_PS_AUDITTRAIL PSA  
INNER JOIN MUSER USR ON USR.LSEQID = PSA.USERID 
INNER JOIN C_WF_PS_WORKFLOW WF ON WF.WORKFLOWID = PSA.WORKFLOWID
INNER JOIN C_CSC_PS_CACHE CSC ON CSC.POLICYNO = WF.POLICYNO
WHERE WF.POLICYNO = CSC.POLICYNO
AND  MONTH (PSA.CREATEDATE) = @month AND YEAR(PSA.CREATEDATE) = @year
```

[image]

Comment: `DE_Name` is different between 2 rows. So it's correct.

Comment: yes, why it taking NULL as DE_name, how to ignore it in sql server?

Comment: `Where DE_name is not null`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`DE_Name` is different between 2 rows. So it's correct.

To resolve your problem, just do it

```
WHERE WF.POLICYNO = CSC.POLICYNO and DE_name is not null
```

However, the root causes problem is you just need to select some columns that you make sure that it is unique and make sense.

Comment: i tried using is not null but still getting same result.  
**WHERE WF.POLICYNO = CSC.POLICYNO and DE_Name is not null and psa.CREATEDATE is not null**
i added order by **CSC.POLICYNO** as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a group by end of the lines.

```
SELECT DISTINCT CSC.POLICYNO 
    ,PSA.WORKFLOWID 
    ,CSC.POLICYHOLDERNAME
    ,CSC.TASKTYPE 
    ,CSC.PRODUCTCODE
    ,WF.STATUS
    ,(SELECT concat(USR.SFIRSTNAME, USR.SLASTNAME) where USR.lseqid = (select psa.userid where psa.actiontype IN(602))) AS DE_Name
    ,PSA.CREATEDATE AS DE_Start_date
    ,(SELECT UPDATEDATE FROM C_WF_PS_AUDITTRAIL WHERE WORKFLOWID = PSA.WORKFLOWID AND  ACTIONTYPE IN (603) ) as DE_End_date
    FROM C_WF_PS_AUDITTRAIL PSA  
    INNER JOIN MUSER USR ON USR.LSEQID = PSA.USERID 
    INNER JOIN C_WF_PS_WORKFLOW WF ON WF.WORKFLOWID = PSA.WORKFLOWID
    INNER JOIN C_CSC_PS_CACHE CSC ON CSC.POLICYNO = WF.POLICYNO
    WHERE WF.POLICYNO = CSC.POLICYNO
    AND  MONTH (PSA.CREATEDATE) = @month AND YEAR(PSA.CREATEDATE) = @year
    **GROUP BY ......**
```

Comment: When i add "Group BY" ,i'm getting error

**Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
Column 'PSA.WORKFLOWID' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.**

Comment: In the Group by clause you have to mention all the attributes you entered in the select .
GROUP BY CSC.POLICYNO,PSA.WORKFLOWID ,CSC.POLICYHOLDERNAME ...